# Python/pandas conditional statement based on date_time index values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a Pandas dataframe with a time series index based on a date range applied using date_time, as follows:

```
                     Column A
2016-11-24 00:00:00  4.0
2016-11-24 01:00:00  7.8
2016-11-24 02:00:00  95.1
2016-11-24 03:00:00  78.4
etc
```

What I'd like to do is create a new column that applies a factor to Column A based on the month in the index.

Correction factors: September = 1, October = 2, November = 3, December = 4, etc.

So, in the example above case, because the month is November, the result would be:

```
                     Column A   Column B
2016-11-24 00:00:00  4.0        12
2016-11-24 01:00:00  7.8        23.4
2016-11-24 02:00:00  95.1       285.3
2016-11-24 03:00:00  78.4       235.2
etc
```

I have tried a number of solutions some trouble with this. Does anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can substract `8` from [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and then `multiple`, but in months before `September` get numbers less as `1`:

```
print (df.index.month - 8)
[3 3 3 3]

df['Column B'] = df['Column A'] * (df.index.month - 8)
print (df)
                     Column A  Column B
2016-11-24 00:00:00       4.0      12.0
2016-11-24 01:00:00       7.8      23.4
2016-11-24 02:00:00      95.1     285.3
2016-11-24 03:00:00      78.4     235.2
```

You can also use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` and then multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html). In this solution is necessary create `Series` from `df.index.month` which return `numpy array` with index of `df` (if not `index`, get all values `NaN` because indexes not match).

```
d = {9:1,10:2,11:3,12:4}

df['Column B'] = pd.Series(df.index.month, index=df.index).map(d).mul(df['Column A'])
print (df)
                     Column A  Column B
2016-11-24 00:00:00       4.0      12.0
2016-11-24 01:00:00       7.8      23.4
2016-11-24 02:00:00      95.1     285.3
2016-11-24 03:00:00      78.4     235.2
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with your second method. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Super, I am glad can help you!